# Ubuntu boots to tty1 after 16.04.1 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

I tried to update to 16.04.1 and it went fine, and then when I restarted, I picked Ubuntu and it boots, and then it goes to a username/login screen which I do and it loads and goes to text:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu
username@username:~$
```

and wants an entry ???

HELP!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45936/discussion-on-question-by-user301732-ubuntu-boots-to-tty1-after-16-04-1-upgrade).

Comment: hey, did you find a solution to this one? did you upgrade a ubuntu installation **inside** a virtual(box)?